# C++ and Qt, how do I run either the constructor function or a different function on object creation to setup a Ui?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

In Qt, I have a class with a slot, called on_pushButton_2_clicked(), in this function, I would like to instantiate another class, `Login`, and run `setupUi` on its ui element.

Currently, this is what I have:

in WelcomeScreen.cpp

```
void WelcomeScreen::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Login login(this);
    login.init();
}
```

and in Login.cpp

```
void Login::init(){
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPalette wPal(palette());
    wPal.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::white);
    ui->success->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    ui->success->setPalette(wPal);
    ui->success->hide();
    ui->failure->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    ui->failure->setPalette(wPal);
    ui->failure->hide();
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, but it doesn't load the login ui upon the button press. This, does load the UI:

In WelcomeScreen.cpp

```
void WelcomeScreen::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Ui::Login login_ui;
    login_ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

However, it doesn't run the `Login` constructor or any of its functions so I can't initialize it like I'd like to.

Ideally, I'd like to simply instantiate the `Login` object and have it run the constructor, thus setting up the Ui and running all of the initialization.

Also, here's the `Login` constructor (it's basically the default constructor)

```
Login::Login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Login)
{
init();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `WelcomeScreen::on_pushButton_2_clicked()` function, your `Login` object will be destroyed once the function finishes. This is because it goes out of scope. You can solve this by either initializing it with `new`, or making it a member variable. You can also use `QSharedPointer` or a similar class.

I don't know how your `Login` class is supposed to work, so in my example I will delete it when it is closed.

```
void WelcomeScreen::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Login *login = new Login(this);
    login->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    login->init();
}
```

Comment: That didn't work... So, if it's destroyed at the end of the function, using the explicit constructor `new Login(this)` will prevent it from closing? It still seems to be doing the same thing... Also, why did you include `WA_DeleteOnClose`?

Comment: @JVE999 What kind of class is your `Login` class? Is it to supposed to be in its own window (i.e dialog)? The reason i use `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` is because i'm assuming it's a dialog. So I want to delete it when it's closed so I wont have many of these objects littering around, because they aren't being deleted, and I'm creating a new one each time button is pressed.

Comment: @JVE999 I see it's a main window. Try calling `login->show();`.

Comment: Good point. I figured they would get unloaded/deconstructed, but I guess there's not really a call for that unless it's hidden in Qt somewhere. It's a Ui Form class that inherits QMainWindow, just like the default MainWindow class of the Qt Widgets template

Comment: That worked! However, the other window is left open. How would I delete that one? -- EDIT: I found `QMainWindow->close()` or in this case, `ui->close()`, to close it.

Comment: Also, since it's opening multiple windows instead of replacing the contents, would there be any trouble with running this on a phone?

Comment: @JVE999 I don't think it should cause any problems on the phone, but I am not 100% sure. It's worth testing out first. If you want to delete your `WelcomeScreen` you can just call `this->close();`. Note that if you delete it, your `Login` window will also be deleted as you set a parent to it. To keep it alive, initialize it without a parent: `Login *login = new Login;`

Comment: Edit to say `this->close()` in previous comment by me

Comment: I should say, If you want to close your `WelcomeScreen` you can just call `this->close();`. This will not necessarily delete it.